# Why I can't get estimated execution plan? How to check that query had initiated statistics update?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, blob

This executes in several seconds:

```
DECLARE @FILES_IDS TABLE
(
    ID int,
    fc int NULL
)

INSERT INTO @FILES_IDS
SELECT id, datalength(FILE_CONTENT)
FROM FILES with (nolock) 

DELETE FROM @FILES_IDS WHERE fc is not null

SELECT * FROM @FILES_IDS
```

but this (that should bring the same recordset) never ends:

```
SELECT id, datalength(FILE_CONTENT)
FROM FILES with (nolock) 
WHERE datalength(FILE_CONTENT) is null
```

I even can't get "estimated execution plan"!!! (waiting for 20 mintes without any result) This is possibly the key to the undestanding what is going here... So the question could be reformated that way: **in which cases we have to wait a lot for "estimated execution plans"?**

P.S. table definition simple but table contains about million of blobs (size of the table 200 GB), there is the PK on ID:

```
CREATE TABLE [FILES](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FILE_CONTENT] [varbinary](max) NULL)
```

**Added**. I get the estimated execution plan after 30 min. But this execution plan contains absolutely the same "Clustered Index Scan" as first query. And, siurprise, second and last executions were finnished is several seconds... IO problem? Wrong execution plan till that?

**Added 2**. UPDATE STATISTICS FILES - runs slow (30 min, btw this number is comparable to the number of minutes to read 200 gb on that system), and after it select operation become quick. So all is clear? No. Because :

1. I can't understand how I should act next time when I will be unable
   to get an estimated exceution plan? How to check that query
   is slow down on statistics update?
2. I can't understand why UPDATE STATISTICS need to read blobs???

Comment: Sounds like a locking issue. `sp_who2` or `sp_lock`. Who is blocking your process? Or, it could be statistics gathering. But 20min?! That's a lot even for a 70GB table.

Comment: Since `DATALENGTH()` will only return `NULL` for a `NULL` input, why are you using that in your `WHERE` clause rather than the simpler `WHERE FILE_CONTENT IS NULL`?

Comment: There is "nolock" inside query, so I think lock problems where excluded... "Statistics" is good assumption. I should read documentation, does the "estimated plan" initiates recalculation of it ...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : actualy I have started from condition 
"FILE_CONTENT IS NULL", but after several attempts to get results, I have started to experiment with query (may be it can be called 
"a panic" :) . Note: the query without "WHERE" (just select id, datalength(FILE_CONTENT)) worked well!

Comment: Nolock does not do what you think it does. It does not remove all locking and blocking. Check for blocking.

Comment: @usr : do you want to say that table lock  could prevent getting estimated execution plan? I have just experimented with it: locked the table with TABLOCKX for some time and wrote the select: select "never ends", but estimated execution plan was retrieved without any delay.  P.S. I expect that "nolock" is eqeal to "read uncommited", nothing more.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij there are locks that do not lock data but schema. Try: `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE; begin tran; truncate T;`. This should prevent a plan from being compiled. Or, modify a column, switch a partition, ...; Your suspicion about nolock is correct.

Comment: I'll also repeat my advice: Look under the hood and see what the blocked statement is waiting for. SQL Server *tells you* what the problem is.

Comment: @usr : yes of course he tells me, the question is to learn how to hear what he tells. the sp_who2 doesn't show BlkBy spid, the process is just RUNNABLE (It seems I can stabily repeat the situation: massive BLOB update/insert, and the first select after it).

Answer (score 1):

When auto stats is on, SQL Server will create the statistics for the necessary columns when needed. When you ask for the estimated query plan SQL Server will create the statistics for the `FILE_CONTENT` column because it is used in the where clause and that can take some time depending on what sample rate is used and how many rows you have in the table. To check if SQL Server really did create the statistics or not you can have a look at what statistics you have before you ask for the query plan and after. There should be one added named `_WA_Sys_...` that wasn't there before.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I want to discuss it: 1) "you can have a look .. AFTER." I am not happy with this "after"!!! Do we have a way to get the information that query hangs because of statistics update in the "middle" (with those iSCSI I allways suspect IO problems, so I do not want to wait for hours to become sure that this is just "statistics"). 2) for better understanding may be you can explain what kind of statistics Sql Server  collects reading blobs? Time? But it depends on size, and I know that select sum(datalength(FILE_CONTENT)) -- getting the size -- is almost momental.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij the content in the statistics looks about the same as for other statistics. Density and a histogram of 200 steps. As for detecting an update of statistics I guess you could use extended events. This blog post may have some answers for you ( I have not read it yet). http://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/sql-performance/another-way-to-view-auto-statistics

Answer (score -1):

Seeing you're on SQL Server 2012, have you considered a [Filtered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)? It would probably be the easiest way to get this to run.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_filesFiltered ON files WHERE FILE_CONTENT IS NOT NULL`
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm interested more in understanding what is the reason why I can't get "estimated execution plan". If I would get it I would be able to answer on the root question "what is going on and how I can improove query? " .

Comment: The answer to the question "What is going on?" is you are reading a blob, this is a slow process and there is no way around this. I suspect running "SELECT File_ID FROM [Files] WHERE FILE_CONTENT IS NULL" WIll be much much faster.

Comment: No I have tried FILE_CONTENT IS NULL and  also get "never ended query".